# How to print ESLint progress as it runs, but not everything at once when all files are processed?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, prettier-eslint

When running ESLint, nothing is print out until the whole process is done. How can I see the progress as it processed different files, instead of waiting until everything is done?

Comment: Link to ESLint issue: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/1101

Answer (score 17):

On my mind, `--debug` output is too spammy, try to reduce it:

```bash
# eslint ./src & ./config folders with printing the processed files
DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine yarn eslint ./{src,config}

# OR:
# for NPM or other dependency manager
# eslint ./src & ./config folders with printing the processed files
DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine eslint ./{src,config}
```

As a result, you will have a list of files that processed by CLI.

Comment: Hi @Oleksandr Kucherenko, I like your suggestion! to complement your `yarn` method, here is what I did for `npm` by running this: `DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine eslint .` instead.

Comment: Use `DEBUG=eslint:flat-eslint` if you're using `eslint.config.js` AKA a flat config.

Answer (score 5):

Use debug option will print out the progress:

`npx eslint . --debug`

Edit after @Oleksandr Kucherenko suggestion to see a more concise result:
`DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine eslint .`